# Uploading Image to Azure from Android

Tags: android, azure

Is there any library to upload images to Azure from an Android Platform. i have been searching for a tutorial but have not been able to find any ?

Comment: Do take a look at this blog post: http://chrisrisner.com/Storing-Images-from-Android-in-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Mobile Services, there's a nice walk through here: http://chrisrisner.com/Android-and-Mobile-Services-and-Windows-Azure-Storage